# How to add checkbox on all the listView items after having a long item click? Android Java

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I want to add a feature on my project where if the user clicks one of the items on the listView then a checkbox would appear allowing the user to delete 1 or many items at once. Similar to Samsung Notes when you want to delete notes and or folders, etc. However, this concept is completely foreign to me and currently, I don't know where to begin to start this or what topic/resource/sample code I should look for. Also, I have a custom Array Adapter class that I used to order to work with my ListView but it came to my knowledge that you only need 1 array adapter class to make this work which made me confused since I don't know where to begin to manipulate it even further. Any help would be amazing!

Here is my Array Adapter that I have at the moment

````
//want to create our own custom ArrayAdapter. Going to extends the base class ArrayAdapter and hold our
//Word object
public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<WordFolder> {
    //constructor - it takes the context and the list of words
    WordAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<WordFolder> word){
        super(context, 0, word);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if(listItemView == null){
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.folder_view, parent, false);
        }

        //Getting the current word
        WordFolder currentWord = getItem(position);
        //making the 3 text view to match our word_folder.xml
        TextView date_created = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.date_created);

        TextView title = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.title);

        TextView desc = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.desc);

        //using the setText to get the text and set it in the textView
        date_created.setText(currentWord.getDateCreated());

        title.setText(currentWord.getTitle());

        desc.setText(currentWord.getTitleDesc());

        return listItemView;

    }

}```
````

Comment: Wel first add a checkbox to the layout of your listitem. Then make it such that when you scroll the checked items keep their state. Then make it as such as when you rotate the device the checked items keep state. When you are done then come back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R.layout.folder_view add one and make it invisible or gone. OnLongClick make them Visible.